# How can i restore my Suspended Virtual Machine On Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcp-compute-instance

About 1 month later I did crypto mining on my VM and then got a alert and then i just deleted that VM and then I created a new VM to do Codes and after a month GCP deleted my VM and said that i violated their Terms of service and then said me to request a appeal to restore my project and i appealed them and after half an hour they said me that:

Dear Developer,
Thank you for your appeal.

Based on either additional information you provided or further analysis we performed, we have reinstated resources associated with project ***Project Name***. Please fix any outstanding issues to ensure that your project complies with the Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service and Acceptable Use Policy.

We sincerely apologize for any inconvenience you experienced here. We greatly appreciate both your business and your patience.

GO TO MY CONSOLE
Sincerely,
Google Cloud Platform Trust & Safety

But after waiting for nearly 5 hours my VM is not yet Restored and in the Activity column its saying that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjAdh.png)

They said me that they Reinstated my Project it means they must restore my VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a project has been [shut down](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects?hl=en&ref_topic=6158848&visit_id=638126942475014334-3021590162&rd=1#shutting_down_projects), resources under that project gets deleted too.

Thus, deleted VM instances/snapshots/disks are not recoverable after project deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The VM may have been deleted if it violated the terms of service.